# How to have a string that change it value over time based in another string?

Tags: javascript, string, logical-operators

There is any way to make a code that pick a random between these values:

```
let initialString = "single result:\nfoo||bar||anything||something"
let endString
setInterval(()=>{
    endString = // do some stuff do define its value
    console.log(endString)
},1000)
```

Comment: Put the possibilities in an array. Then select a random array element and assign it to `endString`.

Comment: What does this have to do with logical operators? They operate on true/false values, not strings and arrays.

Comment: You can use the `split()` method to extract the words from `initialString`. Please show what you tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array for picking a random array element.

Comment: Are you aware that `setInterval()` function works indefinitely until you stop it? I don't what you're trying to implement but it is not going in a good direction.

Comment: @jkalandarov the initial ideia was to make it run indefinitely

Comment: @Barmar the data comes in a string from a textarea tag, and i don't know if the possibilities will come at start, end or middle of the string, because of it i need to parse the string before of picking the parts that need to be replaced and doing it

Comment: @Thank you for the tip to pick a random from array, as you can see in the answer i've used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that for my application is better to put the possibilities between parentheses to separate then from the parts of the string that don't need to be touched

```
let initialString = "single result:\n(foo|bar|anything|something)"
let endString
let stringChangeInterval = setInterval(() => {
    let validatedPairs = []
    for(let i = 0; i < initialString.length; i++){
        if(initialString[i] != "(") continue
        for(let j = i+1; j < initialString.length; j++){
            if(initialString[j] != ")") continue
            validatedPairs.push([i, j])
            i = j
            break
        }
    }
    endString = initialString
    for(let i = validatedPairs.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        let possibilities =  initialString.substring(validatedPairs[i][0]+1, validatedPairs[i][1]).split('|')
        if(possibilities.length ===  1) continue
        let choosenPossibilty = randomFromArray(possibilities)
        endString = endString.replace(endString.substring(validatedPairs[i][0], validatedPairs[i][1]+1), choosenPossibilty)
    }
    console.log(endString)
}, 1000);

function randomFromArray(array){
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}
```

***EDIT:***

The code above works fine if there is no repeated possibilities, otherwise the code will have a complete misbehavior, so I've made some adjustment to the code:

```js
let initialString = "single result:\n(foo|bar|anything|something)"
let endString
let stringChangeInterval = setInterval(() => {
    let validatedPairs = []
    for(let i = 0; i < initialString.length; i++){
        if(initialString[i] != "(") continue
        for(let j = i+1; j < initialString.length; j++){
            if(initialString[j] != ")") continue
            validatedPairs.push([i, j])
            i = j
            break
        }
    }
    endString = initialString
    for(let i = validatedPairs.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        let possibilities =  initialString.substring(validatedPairs[i][0]+1, validatedPairs[i][1]).split('|')
        if(possibilities.length ===  1) continue
        let choosenPossibilty = randomFromArray(possibilities)
        let lastIndex = endString.lastIndexOf(endString.substring(validatedPairs[i][0], validatedPairs[i][1]+1))
        endString = endString.substring(0, lastIndex)+choosenPossibilty+endString.substring(lastIndex + validatedPairs[i][1]+1 - validatedPairs[i][0])
    }
    console.log(endString)
}, 1000);

function randomFromArray(array){
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`@barmar`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested in his comment, You can simply achieve that by splitting a `initialString` into an array with the help of [`Array.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and then find the random element from that array and print it out.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let initialString = "single result:\nfoo||bar||anything||something";

const arrString = initialString.split('||');

function getRandomItem(arr) {
    // get random index value
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    // get random item
    const endString = arr[randomIndex];
    return endString;
}

console.log(getRandomItem(arrString));
```